# Convert Varchar to ANY time format

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, cognos, cognos-10

I have a varchar column called `begin_time` that stores the 24-hour time as a varchar with no time formatting, ie `1330`

**I need to convert this varchar to a usable timestamp, datetime, etc. where I can easily convert the varchar to a standard time format (`1:30 PM`)**

*The end format type doesn't matter* as long as I can convert the varchar into a format that I can manipulate to a standard format.

I've tried looking into [Cognos-specific format tricks](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_10.2.1/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_md.10.2.1.doc/c_crxreportcastingfunctions.html) (These functions are for Metric Designer, and I'm using Report Studio) to no avail. The methods I found when looking for oracle-specific tricks seemed to be way too convoluted (using insanely long regex rules) for what I need.

If I need to have a date involved, I can use the column `start_date` and append the varchar time.
**Note:** `start_date` is in the `date` format

**Example**

```
select 
to_date('08/27/2018','MM/DD/YYYY') as start_date
, '1300' as begin_time
from dual
```

What I ultimately need is just to be able to output the time as `1:00 PM`

Any help would be appreciated. I'm beating my head against the wall on this... I'm used to using proprietary codes for periods of time and don't have a lot of experience with the true datetime formats.

### Updates answering questions

- Alex Poole, I make no claims that this system is the best... It's vendor-provided. :)
- The `BEGIN_TIME` is always 4 characters
- It does look like I was overthinking it quite a bit... Littlefoot may have nailed it on the head, but I unfortunately won't have a chance to test that until tomorrow.

**Thank you all for the fast responses. I might have hair left when this request is over now :)**

### Final Thought

My lesson learned from this is simple: If you're dealing with time formats, don't throw out the idea of using a *Date* format function.

Comment: I think you're overthinking things. Oracle can convert times just like dates, for example, `to_date('08/27/2018 1300','MM/DD/YYYY hh24mi')` returns a datetime

Comment: Are your strings always four characters (i.e. zero-padded, like '0123')? Are you sue there are no values which don't actually represent a real time? (And why are you storing the time separately in the first place!?)

Comment: Assuming that the values of the `begin_time` column are always 4 characters long, you can simply use `SELECT TO_DATE(begin_time, 'HH24MI')` to convert it to a date/time value, then ignore the date part (by default, it will be today's date!) when formatting it for display.

Comment: It will be the first day of the current month, not today; as Littlefoot said *8-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking for this?

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '1330' from dual)
  3  select to_char(to_date(col, 'hh24mi'), 'hh:mi am') result
  4  from test;

RESULT
--------
01:30 PM

SQL>
```

What does it do?

- `TO_DATE` converts string you have (such as `1330`) into a valid DATE value. By default, it'll be a date value truncated to the first of current month:

  ```
  SQL> alter session set nls_Date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:Mi';

  Session altered.

  SQL> select to_date('1330', 'hh24mi') res1 from dual;

  RES1
  ----------------
  01.04.2019 13:30

  SQL>
  ```
- applying `TO_CHAR` to it, again with the appropriate format mask, returns the desired result

Comment: Thank you all for your help! Littlefoot nailed it on the head. Cognos is now giving me a "non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected" error, but I can track that down and fix it. That's the exact format I was looking for. Thank you!